# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{MainFrag}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Hello I'm working on an application that is going to be android  launcher there are three different screens in this launcher the first screen is a bookshelf that is supposed to import and Show all books in the SD card place on the device the second is a calculator (works just fine!) Third is a Homework page where you can make google drive docs and flashcards (also works fine!!) I get no errors when I run my code the app automatically crashes when it launches on my device and on the emulator.

Heres my Logcat:

```
11-23 15:05:06.314: E/SurfaceFlinger(323): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
11-23 15:05:15.084: E/Trace(3807): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
11-23 15:05:15.254: E/AndroidRuntime(3807): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-23 15:05:15.254: E/AndroidRuntime(3807): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.d4a.tobias/it.gmariotti.android.examples.googleaccount.MainFrag}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-23 15:05:15.254: E/AndroidRuntime(3807):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
11-23 15:05:15.254: E/AndroidRuntime(3807):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
11-23 15:05:15.254: E/AndroidRuntime(3807):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-23 15:05:15.254: E/AndroidRuntime(3807):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
11-23 15:05:15.254: E/AndroidRuntime(3807):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-23 15:05:15.254: E/AndroidRuntime(3807):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-23 15:05:15.254: E/AndroidRuntime(3807):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
11-23 15:05:15.254: E/AndroidRuntime(3807):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-23 15:05:15.254: E/AndroidRuntime(3807):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-23 15:05:15.254: E/AndroidRuntime(3807):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
11-23 15:05:15.254: E/AndroidRuntime(3807):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
11-23 15:05:15.254: E/AndroidRuntime(3807):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-23 15:05:15.254: E/AndroidRuntime(3807): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-23 15:05:15.254: E/AndroidRuntime(3807):     at com.sibext.android_shelf.adapter.ShelfAdapter.setToListView(ShelfAdapter.java:70)
11-23 15:05:15.254: E/AndroidRuntime(3807):     at it.gmariotti.android.examples.googleaccount.MainFrag.onCreate(MainFrag.java:78)
11-23 15:05:15.254: E/AndroidRuntime(3807):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
11-23 15:05:15.254: E/AndroidRuntime(3807):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
11-23 15:05:15.254: E/AndroidRuntime(3807):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
11-23 15:05:15.254: E/AndroidRuntime(3807):     ... 11 more
11-23 15:05:15.354: E/SurfaceFlinger(323): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
11-23 15:05:15.824: E/SurfaceFlinger(323): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
11-23 15:07:05.354: E/SurfaceFlinger(323): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
```

Heres MainFrag.java:

```
package it.gmariotti.android.examples.googleaccount;


    import java.io.File;

    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.res.AssetManager;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.Window;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.d4a.tobias.R;
    import com.sibext.android_shelf.ImportBooks;
    import com.sibext.android_shelf.adapter.ShelfAdapter;


    public class MainFrag extends FragmentActivity{

           private MyAdapter mAdapter;
        private ViewPager mPager;
        //Shelf
        private static final String TARGET_DIRECTORY = "mnt/sdcard/shelf/";
        private ListView list;


        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

                setContentView(R.layout.mainfrag);


                mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
                mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
                mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

          //      TitlePageIndicator titleIndicator = (TitlePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.titles);
           //     titleIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);           
                //  pts=(PagerTitleStrip)findViewById(R.id.pager_title_strip);

                //Shelf

                File dir = new File(TARGET_DIRECTORY);
                if(!dir.exists()){
                    dir.mkdirs();
                    //past here
                    addBooksFromAssetsToCard();
                }else{
                    String files[] = dir.list();
                    if(files.length == 0){
                        //past here
                        addBooksFromAssetsToCard();
                    }
                }

                list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

                ShelfAdapter adapter = new ShelfAdapter(this, TARGET_DIRECTORY);
                adapter.setToListView(list);

        }
        public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
           String arr[]={"Calculator","Books","Homework"};

           public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
                        super(fm);
                }
                @Override
                public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return arr[position];
                }
                @Override
                public int getCount() {
                        return arr.length;
                }
                @Override
                public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                        switch (position) {
                        case 0:
                                return new Calculator();
                        case 1:
                                return new Book();

                        case 2:
                            return new Homework();

                        default:
                                return null;
                        }
                }
        }
    //Shelf

        public void addBooksFromAssetsToCard(){
            List<String> books;
            try {
                books = getBooksFromAsset(getApplicationContext());

                for(String book : books){
                    copyFromAssets(book);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }

        public List<String> getBooksFromAsset(Context ctx) throws Exception
        {
            AssetManager assetManager =ctx.getAssets();
            String[] files = assetManager.list("books");
            List<String> it=Arrays.asList(files);
            return it;
        }

        public void copyFromAssets(String book)
        {
            AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
            String[] files = null;
            InputStream in = null;
            OutputStream out = null;
            //String filename = "filename.ext";
            try
            {
                in = assetManager.open("books/"+book);
                out = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"/shelf/"+book);
                Log.d("Copying...", ""+book);
                copyFile(in, out); 
                in.close();
                in = null;
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                out = null;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            { 
                Log.e("tag", "Failed to copy asset file: " + book, e);
            }      
        }
        public void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws Exception
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int read;
            while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
            {
                out.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            Log.d("Copy_State", "Done...");
        }

        public void onImportClicked(View v){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please wait...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ImportBooks.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }


    }
```

EDIT ADDED Shelf Adapter.java :

```
package com.sibext.android_shelf.adapter;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.d4a.tobias.R;
import com.sibext.android_shelf.MainActivity;
import com.sibext.android_shelf.shelf.ShelfItem;

public class ShelfAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private static final int ROW_COUNT_DEFAULT = 2;
    private static final int ROW_COUNT_LAND_DEFAULT = 4;
    private static final int ROW_HEIGHT_DEFAULT = 150;

    private Context context;

    private int rowCount = ROW_COUNT_DEFAULT;
    private int rowCountLand = ROW_COUNT_LAND_DEFAULT;
    private int rowHeight = ROW_HEIGHT_DEFAULT;

    private SparseArray<LoadPreviewTask> taskPool;

    private ArrayList<ShelfItem> items;
    String PATH;
    ShelfItem item;


    public ShelfAdapter(Context context, String targetDir) {
        this.context = context;

        items = new ArrayList<ShelfItem>();
        taskPool = new SparseArray<ShelfAdapter.LoadPreviewTask>();

        if (targetDir == null || context == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("ShelfAdapter: wrong paramenters - " +
                    (targetDir == null ? "Target directory " : "Context ") + "is null");
        }

        File dir = new File(targetDir);
        if(dir.exists() && dir.isDirectory()){
            for(File f : dir.listFiles()){
                if(f != null && f.getName().endsWith(".pdf")){
                    items.add(new ShelfItem(f));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void setToListView(ListView list){
        list.setDividerHeight(0);
        list.setAdapter(this);
    }

    public void setRowCount(int rowCount, int rowCountLand) {
        this.rowCount = rowCount;
        this.rowCountLand = rowCountLand;
    }

    public void setRowHeight(int rowHeight) {
        this.rowHeight = rowHeight;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        int sub = getSubItemsCount(); 
        return (int)(sub/getRowCount()) + (sub%getRowCount() == 0 ? 0 : 1);
    }

    public int getSubItemsCount(){
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ShelfItem getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView == null){
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.shelf_row, null);
            AbsListView.LayoutParams itemParams = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
                    AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, rowHeight);
            convertView.setLayoutParams(itemParams);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams subItemParams = getSubViewParams();
            for(int i = 0; i < getRowCount(); i++){
                View sub = getSubView(getSubPosition(position, i), null);
                sub.setLayoutParams(subItemParams);
                ((ViewGroup)convertView).addView(sub);
                holder.subViews.add(sub);
            }
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            for(int i = 0; i < holder.subViews.size(); i++){
                getSubView(getSubPosition(position, i), holder.subViews.get(i));
            }
        }
        return convertView;
    }


    public View getSubView(final int position, View convertView){
        final SubViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.shelf_item, null);
            holder = new SubViewHolder();
            holder.img = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.shelf_item_image);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (SubViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        if(position >= getSubItemsCount()){
            holder.img.setImageBitmap(null);
            return convertView;
        }

        item = getItem(position);
        PATH = item.getFile().getAbsolutePath();
        Bitmap preview = item.getPreviewFromSD();
        if(preview != null){
            holder.img.setImageBitmap(preview);
        } else {
            holder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            LoadPreviewTask task = taskPool.get(holder.hashCode());
            if (task != null) {
                task.cancel(true);
                taskPool.remove(holder.hashCode());
                task = null;
            }
            task = new LoadPreviewTask(holder, rowHeight);
            taskPool.put(holder.hashCode(), task);
            task.execute(item);
        }

        holder.img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final ShelfItem si = items.get(position);
                /*Toast.makeText(context, "Item #" + position+"\n"+si.getFile().getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                */

                final CharSequence[] items = {"View", "Delete"};
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                builder.setTitle("Please choose:");
                builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+items[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int index) {
                        if(index == 0){
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(si.getFile()),"application/pdf");
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                            context.startActivity(intent);
                        }else if(index == 1){
                                     File file = new File(si.getFile().getAbsoluteFile().toString());
                                     boolean deleteStatus = file.delete();
                                     if(deleteStatus){
                                         Toast.makeText(context, "Deleted Successfully...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                                         Intent in = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                                         context.startActivity(in);

                                     }else{
                                         Toast.makeText(context, "Unable to delete...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                     }
                        }
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();

            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

    private int getSubPosition(int listItemPosition, int offset){
        return listItemPosition * getRowCount() + offset;
    }

    private LinearLayout.LayoutParams getSubViewParams(){
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        p.weight = 1f;
        return p;
    }

    private int getRowCount() {
        return context.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT 
                ? rowCount : rowCountLand;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder{
        public ArrayList<View> subViews;

        public ViewHolder() {
            this.subViews = new ArrayList<View>();
        }
    }

    private static class SubViewHolder{
        public ImageView img;
    }

    private class LoadPreviewTask extends AsyncTask<ShelfItem, Void, Bitmap>{
        private SubViewHolder holder;
        private int rowHeight;

        public LoadPreviewTask(SubViewHolder holder, int rowHeight) {
            super();
            this.holder = holder;
            this.rowHeight = rowHeight;
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(ShelfItem... params) {
            ShelfItem item = (ShelfItem)params[0];
            Bitmap preview = item.getPreview(rowHeight);
            item.savePreview(preview);
            return preview;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Bitmap result) {
            if(isCancelled()){
               holder = null;
               return;
            }
            holder.img.setImageBitmap(result);
            taskPool.remove(holder.hashCode());
        }
    }

}
```

I'm still fairly new to Android so please don’t judge and any help will be greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to post the code for ShelfAdapter. It's line 70 of that which is throwing the NPE.

Comment: added it to post please check it out thanks!

Comment: Double check that you have a `ListView` in your mainfrag.xml layout file defined with `android:id="@+id/list` - even better, post your mainfrag.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

`list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);` returns null because your list is not created yet. Override the `onViewCreated()` and put your code in there.

Comment: Huh? Can you explain that?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply I'm still learning can you please be a little more specific? thanks!!!

Comment: @user2977501 : The reason I started my comment (above) with "Huh?" is because the answer from grexter89 makes no sense.

Comment: sure, your `NullPointerException` occurs on this line (i guess): `adapter.setToListView(list);`. this is because `list` is `null`.

Comment: ok so what would I put instead of null?? thanks for the quick reply :)

Comment: i'm not really sure anymore about my answer. but i'm sure, list is null

Comment: Basically, but to state it correctly, the null pointer exception occurs *inside the body* of the setToListView() method, where it twice tries to call methods of the passed list object, something that will obviously fail if that object is null.

Comment: @ChrisStratton : Yep, but I'll lay money on the problem being with the mainfrag.xml layout file used for the Activity's content view.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here: adapter.setToListView(list); should be something like: list.setAdapter(...)  but you have another errors on ShelfAdapter.java, can you copy what you have written from line 65 to line 70?

Comment: Not really - the code you suggest turns out to be present inside the setToListView() method, but the problem is that the list is null, and you can't call methods of a null object.